# How to access instance from another function in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa

I am trying to access a webView object from another class.

> viewController.m

```
    @property (strong, nonatomic) TOWebViewController *webViewController;

    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad {

            [super viewDidLoad];

            self.webViewController = [[TOWebViewController alloc]  initWithURLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.%@/", url] ];

            [self setViewControllers:@[_webViewController]];

        }

- (void)request {

     NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];

     NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

     [_webViewController.webView loadRequest:request];

 }
```

TOWebViewController has the webView property to access the webview. When (void)request is called, something starts loading but it does not load it into the webview that was created in viewDidLoad. How do I have it reference the correct webViewController in (void)request?

Comment: What is `[self setViewControllers:@[_webViewController]];` good for?

Comment: I'm not sure actually, I was trying to find a way to reference it

Comment: You are referencing it with `_webViewController` (could be `self.webViewController`).

Comment: I tried self. and it does not work either.

Comment: You already have a reference to your webViewController when allocating it. Maybe issue in the TOWebViewController? Do you have outlet or create webView from code?

Comment: Anyway, what's the exact problem you are running into ("does not load")? You are presenting one view controller and loading the web view of another: what do you expect to happen in the UI?

Comment: [self.view addSubview: self.webViewController.view]; in viewDidLoad in place of [self setViewControllers:@[_webViewController]]; But I don't really understand the design of having a viewcontroller in the viewcontroller.

Comment: It's not displaying/loading the page into the webview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just looked at [TOWebviewController](https://github.com/TimOliver/TOWebViewController/blob/master/TOWebViewController/TOWebViewController.h) on github and it states the following in `TOWebViewController.h`:

```
/**
 The web view used to display the HTML content. You can access it through this
 read-only property if you need to anything specific, such as having it execute arbitrary JS code.

 @warning Usage of the web view's delegate property is reserved by this view controller. Do not set it to another object.
 */
@property (nonatomic,readonly)  UIWebView *webView;
```

So the class doesn't sound like you need to interact with it by accessing it directly.

You more than likely want to just set the `url`:

```
/** 
 Get/set the current URL being displayed. (Will automatically start loading) 
 */
@property (nonatomic,strong)    NSURL *url;
```

So try:

```
- (void)request {

     NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]

     _webViewController.url = url;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use childViewController.

The reference document [UIViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html)

Here are the essential methods you might need to call:

```
addChildViewController:

removeFromParentViewController:

willMoveToParentViewController:

didMoveToParentViewController:
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is what you really want is to display the `UIWebView` inside the "parent" view controller, and that there is no need for a "child" view controller.

Why not do it like this?

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView; // set outlet in IB

@end

@implementation ViewController

// ...

- (void)request {
     NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.google.com"];
     NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url];

     [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}

@end
```